# Link Fallback on Android

Tags: android

I have a link included in an email. The link is to a publicly visible web page When a person clicks that link:

- If the person has installed my app, open the link in the app within a web view.
- If the person has *not* installed my app, open the link on the web.

From my understanding, I can accomplish this on iOS via Universal Links. However, I do not see a way to accomplish this within Android. Every solution that I look at (i.e. App Links), redirects the person to the App Store if they do not have the app installed. However, if they do *not* have the app installed, I want to take them to the web page in their default browser. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding App Links.

How do I redirect the person as described above on Android?